# How to print LLONG_MIN without printf in C?

Tags: c, printing

I declared a variable of type long long and I assigned to it `LLONG_MIN`, but I'm not allowed to do it.

> ft_long_long_to_ascii_base.c:23:14: error: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned [-Werror]

```
if (val == -9223372036854775808)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, integer constant have type `int`, but as the warning shows you, `9223372036854775808` does not fit into an `int`. The `-` is not part of the constant, it's a unary operator (thus, there are no negative integer constants). To make an integer constant of type `long long int`, suffix your integer constant with `LL`:

The warning appears because `9223372036854775808` is too large to fit into a `long long` which is the largest type unsuffixed decimal integer constants can assume (cf. ISO 9899:2011 §6.4.4.1 ¶5). The `-` is actually not part of the constant, it's a unary operator applied to a positive integer constant.

Mentioning the value of `LLONG_MIN` is thus tricky, the second best way (apart from using the constant in `limits.h`) is to do something like this:

```
-9223372036854775807 - 1
```

Comment: Or just use the `LLONG_MIN` macro, and avoid the rigamarole.

Comment: "By default, integer constant have type `int`" is not so.  The type is dependent on its value and the platform as well as suffixes -  See C11 §6.4.4.1 5  Try `printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof (int), sizeof (9223372036854775807));`

Comment: @chux Well, that's interesting. Is that part new? Let me fix my answer.

Comment: C89 does say "An integer character constant has type `int`".  The changed occurred in C99 (Do not think C89 had `long long`).  So using `(-9223372036854775807L - 1)` has _some_ value for backward comparability.  Of course `long long` _could_ be wider than 64-bit and so the value is wrong.  Given these complications - easiest to use `LLONG_MIN`

Answer (score 5):

Rather than guess what `LLONG_MIN` may be, use the macro supplied

```
#include <stdint.h>
if (val == LLONG_MIN)
```